# Ассоциативный массив занести слова по ключам

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива один с буквами алфавита, второй с именами

```
 $name = array("Aндрей","Артур","Ваня","Виталик","Богдан");
 $alf =  array ("А","Б","В");
```

Надо получить вида такого

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aндрей
            [1] => Артур

        )

    [Б] => Array
        (
            [0] => Богдан

        )

 [В] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ваня
            [1] => Виталик
        )
)
```

не выходит правльно организовать циклы чтоб брал первый индекс с алфавита и прогонял через сравнение по массиву имен и добавлял если Первая буква начинается на то Элемент индекса из массива алфавита

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $names = ["Aндрей", "Артур", "Ваня", "Виталик", "Богдан"];
    $alf  = ["А", "Б", "В"];


    $data = [];
    foreach ($alf as $char) {
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            $keyName = mb_substr($name, 0, 1);

            if ($char == $keyName) {
                if (! array_key_exists($char, $data)) {
                    $data[$char] = [];
                }

                $data[$char][] = $name;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. mb_subst следует вызывать с указанием кодировки, если неизвестны настройки окружения, в котором выполняется скрипт. 2. В PHP не следует использовать оператор `==`. Его изобретателю уже приготовлено место в аду. Всегда используйте строгое сравнение `===` – это позволит избежать многих багов.

Comment: @rugabarbo скрипт не является полноценным готовым решением, так как нет открывающих `<?php` та же он, если я не ошибаюсь будет работать на php старше `5.4`, если вы заметили, объявление `массивов` через `[]`. Данный скрипт даёт ответ, как можно построить цикл, что бы достичь нужного результата. По мне он это и делает

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov, то есть проще было написать этот коммент, нежели улучшить пример кода, чтобы он был более универсальным?

Comment: @rugabarbo не известно в каком окружение он будет запускаться, если поставить `encoding` то у разных людей возможно будут ошибки. Насчет `===` вопрос спорный, с которым я не согласен

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov, как раз если НЕ поставить encoding, то у разных людей будут ошибки. Можно послушать Ваши аргументы за оператор несторогого сравнения `==`? Чем он хорош именно в этом случае? Что мы получаем за счёт него?

Comment: Примеры приведите.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
    $name = array("Андрей","Артур","Ваня","Виталик","Богдан");
    $alf =  array ("А","Б","В");
    $output = array();

    foreach ($name as $value) {
        $letter = mb_substr($value, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
        $output[$letter][] = $value;
    }

    ksort($output); //сортируем ключи по алфавиту
    $output = array_intersect_key($output, array_flip($alf)); // Если нужны только те буквы, которые присутствуют в массиве $alf

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($output); echo "</pre>";
```